# How to not always calculate value of parameter that might not be used

Tags: c++

I'm mostly interested in C++ answers for this but in addition C answers would be welcome too as they will probably vary. This is a simplified version of the real code to focus on my question so assume what I've written is correct :P

Imagine I have a function called `process` in a library.
This function takes three parameters, *a*, *b*, and *c*
Most of the time the function only needs the values of *a* and *b* to do it's job but in some circumstances requires *c*.

Now I want to call this from a main program.
`process(1, 2, very_expensive_call(55, 67, "Hello"));`

Imagine that the value of *c* is very expensive to calculate. As it's probably not needed I don't want to calculate it unless I have to.

I don't want my main program to have to repeat the logic of knowing if *c* will be needed. I don't want the library to know about `very_expensive_call`.

So how can I organize my code to prevent the call to the expensive function while remaining both efficient and elegant?

Answer (score 2):

Make it a lazy call, pass a function object that will calculate the value on request:

```
template<typename Expensive>
int process(int, int, Expensive&&);
```

and then you'd call:

```
process(1, 2, []{ return very_expensive_call(55, 67, "Hello"); });
```

If you do not want to make your function a template, use `std::function` for type erasure (or possibly a lighter alternative if there is one that suits your needs):

```
int process(int, int, function<expensive_result()>);
```

with no change at the call site:

```
process(1, 2, []{ return very_expensive_call(55, 67, "Hello"); });
```

This solution will require you to explicitly call the operator `()` in the `process`'s code to get compute the value.

Comment: Well I guess that's fairly obvious now I think about it :)
Thank you.